# Tkinter frameless window moving causes mouse cursor glitch (teleport to the left up corner of the window)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window, move

I use move() function to move the window via this code:

```
window.overrideredirect(True)
def move(event):
    window.geometry(f'+{event.x_root}+{event.y_root}')

title_frame= Frame(window,bg='gray', height=20)
title_frame.bind('<B1-Motion>', move)
title_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill='x')
```

But, when i move the window, the whole window shifts via it's top left corner to the mouse cursor, even if cursor was in the middle of the title_frame, and that causes 'window teleportation' on the screen.

How can i fix it? Or how can i create compact, fast working and no-glitchy window movement?

UPD: And the second problem. With `window.overrideredirect(True)` i can't minimize the window via this func:

```
def minimize():
    window.state('iconic')
```

Comment: Could you give a working example of the code that doesn't give your disired output ?

Comment: The geometry you're supplying will always place the top-left corner of the window at the cursor coordinates. If you want it somewhere else, it's just a matter of doing a little math.

Comment: @OlivierNeve the whole code is actually in the question, except mainloop()

Comment: Are you aware that the format "+x+y" does not mean "add x to the current x coordinate"? It means "move the top-left corner to x".

Comment: @BryanOakley oh, now i recognized that. Thank U) Btw, i can't beat the 'minimizaing' function with frameless window, so, i think that it would be better to build frameless windows on PyQt. Btw, is it possible so create fully movable and resizable frameless window, which ll be shown in the taskbar, via Tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

This will make a borderless window with a draggable titlebar.

```
import tkinter as tk

## Create borderless window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("420x300+400+180")
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.resizable(True, True)

## Create titlebar frame
titlebar = tk.Label(root, bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED)
titlebar.pack(fill=tk.X)

## Create buttons
close = tk.Label(titlebar, text="  x  ", bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
close.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.NE)

minimize = tk.Label(titlebar, text="  -  ", bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
minimize.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.NE)

## Make window draggable
def minim(_e):
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.wm_state("iconic")
    root.overrideredirect(True)

def get_pos(event):
    global xwin
    global ywin
    xwin = event.x
    ywin = event.y

def drag(event):
    root.geometry(f"+{event.x_root - xwin}+{event.y_root - ywin}")

## Setup bindings
close.bind("<Button-1>", lambda _e: root.destroy())
minimize.bind("<Button-1>", minim)
titlebar.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)
titlebar.bind("<Button-1>", get_pos)

root.mainloop()
```

The `get_pos` and `drag` functions make the window draggable. `get_pos` finds the cursor position whenever you click on the titlebar, and `drag` moves the window relative to that position whenever you drag the window.